# Cv tex doesn t work

Tags: errors, moderncv

```
% Exemple de CV utilisant la classe moderncv
% Style classic en bleu
% Article complet : http://blog.madrzejewski.com/creer-cv-elegant-latex-moderncv/

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...


%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
%\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}

\firstname{Laurent\\ \\}
\familyname{Pincemaille}
\title{Ingénierie \& Recherche  en Mathématiques}              
\address{4 rue de l' orangerie}{92190 Meudon}    
\email{laurent.pincemaille.upmc@gmail.com}                      
%\homepage{www.madrzejewski.com}
\mobile{8} 
\extrainfo{ } %\extrainfo{}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{./images/photo_cv.jpg}                  % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file

%\quote{recherche domaine nucléaire}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

 %  


\begin{document}

\maketitle
%\makecvtitle

\section{Formations}
\cventry{2014 -- 2015}{Master 2 Recherche  }{Université Pierre et Marie Curie (UPMC) Paris}{}{}{ Mathématiques de la modélisation, spécialité Optimisation Jeux et Dynamique (OJD)}
\cventry{2013 -- 2014}{Pos-gradação (pour équivalence Master 1)}{Universidad Federal de Santa Catarina, Florianopolis Brasil}{}{}{Dominante en optimisation}
\cventry{2012 -- 2013}{Licence 3}{Université Pierre et Marie Curie (UPMC), Paris}{}{}{}


\cventry{2006 -- 2011}{Diplômé d'école d' ingénieur}{Hautes Etudes d'ingénieurs (HEI), Lille}{}{}{Spécialité mécanique}

\cventry{2005 -- 2006}{Classes préparatoire }{Lycée Buffon, Paris}{}{}{Mathématiques, (MPSI)}

\cventry{2005}{Baccalauréat}{Meudon  (92)}{}{}{Série scientifique}

\section{Experiences Professionnelles}

\cventry{Juillet 2014 -- Septembre 2014}{Stage de recherche (fin d’étude de M2)}{Laboratoire Jacques Louis Lions (LJLL), Paris }{}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Développement  (sous Matlab) de la méthode multipolaire rapide  (Fast Multipole Method) en 1 dimension dans le cadre du calcul du potentiel électrostatique.
\item  Puis modification de la librairie ScalFMM (C++) pour adapter la méthode au regroupement de particules en multipoles.\newline{}
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Juin 2013 -- Août 2013 }{CDD}{IPSL}{Paris}{France}{                                               Validation et étude comparative des modèles de Températures/Pressions   MIMOSA  et ECMWF. \newline{}}

\cventry{Septembre 2012 --  Mai 2013 }{Vacations}{LATMOS (CNRS)}{}{}{    Validation du modèle atmosphérique (potentielle) RACCORD.\newline{}}

\cventry{Juin 2012 -- Août 2012}{CDD}{LATMOS (CNRS, Département Shti/Impec)}{}{}{ Elaboration du site web dédié à ODS:  \url{http://bdap.ipsl.fr/ods/index.html}\newline{}}
%
\cventry{Mai 2011 -- Septembre 2011 }{Stage ingénieur }{EDF R\&D , Département Analyse Mécanique et Accoustique (AMA)}{Clamart}{}{            Prise en compte de l’amortissement fluide exercée sur un assemblage combustible\newline{}}

\cventry{Juin 2010 -- Août 2010  }{Travail d’Etude Recherche (TER) }{INRA}{Lille}{}{Etude hydrodynamique d’un échangeur à plaques corruguées \newline{}}


\cventry{Juin 2010 -- Août 2010 }{ Stage de professionnalisation  }{Ponticelli}{Pierrelatte}{}{Calcul de supportage de tuyauteries pour la centrale EDF de type EPR de Flamanville\newline{}}

\cventry{Juillet 2009 -- Août 2009 }{ Stage d'expatriation }{Observatoire de Prague}{Prague}{}{Dévelopement d’un programme (en Bach) afin de lancer l’exécution automatique de programmes de   calculs liés à l’astronomie \newline{}}

\cventry{Juillet 2007}{ Stage ouvrier }{Baudin Châteauneuf}{Paris}{}{                                               Travail de maintenance dans les théâtres parisiens.\newline{}}


\section{Compétences }
\cvitem{Langues}{Anglais: Bon niveau (titulaire du FCE.), Espagnol (Niveau intermédiaire), Portugais (Niveau intermédiaire: Echange de 6 mois au Brésil)
}
\cvitem{Langages de script}{Matlab, Scilab, Bash}
\cvitem{Dévelopement}{C++ (Notions de base: stage de fin d'étude), Java (Notions de base: module d'un semestre)}
\cvitem{Systèmes}{Windows, Linux (Debian)}

\cvitem{Logiciels Modélisations}{Code Aster, Fluent , Catia (niveau débutant dans les trois)}
\cvitem{Bureautiques}{Open Office, Latex}


%\cvcomputer{Langages}{(X)HTML, PHP, CSS, PL/SQL, C/C++, Java, Bash}{}{}
%\cvcomputer{Base de données}{MySQL, Oracle}{CMS}{Wordpress, Symfony2 (notions)}
%\cvcomputer{Analyse}{Merise, UML, Design Patterns}{}{}
%\cvcomputer{Systèmes}{Windows XP/Seven/Server 2003/Server 2008, Linux (Debian)}{}{}
%\cvcomputer{Administration}{Apache2, BIND, Postfix, Fail2ban, Proxmox (openVZ), Iptables,Nagios}{}{}

\section{Centres d'intérêt}
\cvitem{Sport}{Pratique hebdomadaire  du  basket, futsal et natation}
\cvitem{Association }{: Responsable sport en résidence (organisation de tournois de futsal inter-résidence…)}
%\cvitem{Plongée}{Diplôme de niveau 1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I comment out this line as I have not got the image

```
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{./images/photo_cv.jpg}                  % optional,
```

then the error is

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

which is caused by

```
\firstname{Laurent\\ \\}
```

as there is no line to end for the second `\\` but both `\\` are wrong in that position (the name is just  `\firstname{Laurent}` )